# Elasticsearch How to use specific analyzer and append filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to use `nori` analyzer and synonym filter

I'm not sure if `type` parameter is what I need as below..

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                   "location_analyzer": {
    'type': 'nori',
    'filter': ['location_synonym_filter'],
  },

  "location_synonym_filter": {
    "type": "synonym",
    "expand": True,
    "synonyms_path": "data/synonyms_location",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new custom analyzer since you're adding a new filter. Check out at the definition of that analyzer and then create a new one of type "custom".

Some doc:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-nori-analyzer.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html